# How do I improve this productivity question to become less subjective?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition

I have a question regarding productivity, and it goes like this:

> **Time difference between developing with unit tests vs no tests**
>
> I'm a solo developer with a pretty time-constrained work environment where development time ranges usually from 1-4 weeks per project, depending on either requirements, urgency, or both. At any given time I handle around 3-4 projects, some having timelines that overlap with each other.
>
> Expectedly, code quality suffers. A considerable amount of bugs escape to production, which I have to fix and in turn sets back my other projects.
>
> This is where unit testing comes in. When done right, it should keep bugs, let alone those that escape to production, to a minimum. On the other hand, writing tests can take a considerable amount of time, which doesn't sound good with time-constrained projects such as mine.
>
> Question is, how much of a time difference would writing unit-tested code over untested code, and if possible, how does that time difference scale as project scope widens?

As it is now, I suspect that this would be put off as subjective because it differs from person to person - someone can write unit-tested code as quick as someone else can do the same code but without tests. How can I improve this question so that it doesn't read as such?

**Update:** [Question is now posted at the main site.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/322256/time-difference-between-developing-with-unit-tests-vs-no-tests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this question is "primarily opinion based". Yes, the amount of time it takes to write X lines of code differs from person to person, but you aren't asking us to make such estimates.
Also, it is possible to give an indication of the value of (unit-)tests without going into a specific number of hours.

However, if posted in its current form, I would ask for additional details in another aspect: How are you currently making sure that your code does what it is supposed to be doing. Is the code completely untested, or are you testing the code on a different level than unit tests.

Comment: Thank you. As for the testing, it's at a different level, but informal, so I regarded it as untested.